# Allow raw access to a partition for a particular user

Tags: windows, virtualbox, multi-boot

I have a system that is dual boot Windows/Linux, and VirtualBox installed so that I can also boot Linux in a VM under Windows.

As VirtualBox requires direct access to the Linux partition for this to work, I have to run it with administrator privileges, which I'd rather avoid. Is there a way to grant VirtualBox access to the partition without elevating it?

Comment: To do this, you would have to essentially turn off the Session manager, which is part of the kernel.

Comment: From a naïve point of view, I can do this easily under Linux, by changing the permissions on the device "file". I am fairly certain there should be a mechanism to do something similar in Windows.

Comment: @SimonRichter: Windows *does* have "device files", only in a different [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx) (e.g. `\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2`); they can be viewed using WinObj which unfortunately cannot modify the ACLs, only display them. It's certainly possible to change the ACLs, though; I'm looking for an apropriate tool.

Comment: @surfasb: Why would that require turning off smss?

Comment: @grawity: That's because it doesn't :) I always confuse the Session manager with the Object manager for some reason. My initial thoughts were also to change the ACLs, but I felt it would introduce too many unknowns. Then again, you know the system better than I do.